# Load jquery before jquery-ui when using Flask-Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I need to load jquery-ui for the autocomplete function of jquery, which flask-bootstrap doesn't have.  I added it to the template with this line

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

However, I let Flask-Bootstrap load jquery.js, it always loads it AFTER the template loads jquery-ui, so jquery-ui fails since it requires jquery to be loaded first.

```
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 123ms]
GET http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 181ms]
GET http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 324ms]
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 289ms]
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 111ms]
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment-with-langs.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 175ms]
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:14:2
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

To temporarily solve this, I modified the `__init.py__` of flask-bootstrap to prevent it from loading jquery and manually loaded it in the template.  This page worked but every other page stopped working since jquery wasn't loaded anymore.

Is there any way to make sure flask-bootstrap loads jquery first, then make the template load jquery-ui or flask-bootstrap load jquery-ui itself?

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Project-Z{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1> Members list </h1>
    <h2>Find a member</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#member_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: '{{url_for("main.autocomplete")}}',
            minLength: 2,
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you share the actual code snippet?

Comment: I added the template code, anything else that would make sense to include?

Comment: Do you have github accounnt? May you upload your project to let's understand?

Comment: a bit offttopic, but requirejs maybe something useful for you

Answer (score 4):

Instead of putting the script in the head, I have to put it in the script section so it loads later in the sequence.  This way it loads correctly after the Flask-bootstrap jquery.js loads.  http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/faq.html#how-can-i-add-custom-javascript-to-the-template

```html
{% block scripts %}
  {{super()}}
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Actually you may just create another block container in your base.html template, it looks like twig- read the docs :)

Comment: But this will not load `jquery-ui` before `bootstrap`? Which leads to some feature not to work like Bootstrap Tooltips. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979255/bootstrap-tooltip-css-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If `jquery-ui` is not loaded **after** `jquery` and **before** `bootstrap`, then some bootstrap JS effects may be broken, like in [Bootstrap tooltip css not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979255/bootstrap-tooltip-css-not-working).

It's not ideal, but here is another solution. Do not add the `super()` to your block, and directly copy the original content, adding your `jquery-ui` import at the right place.

```
{% block scripts %}
  <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('jquery.js', cdn='jquery')}}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- Add it here -->
  <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('js/bootstrap.js', cdn='bootstrap')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Original content can be found in the project template https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/3e2695bb36f29bf72befce86c9e63609c3016203/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html#L26-L29