# Bootstrap tooltip css not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to get the tooltip to work, which does btw, but no CSS is applied to the tooltip for reasons unknown. Since the whole site works fine in bootstrap itself (Wordpress plugin), I am scratching my head on this item.

Code is as following.

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $phone;  ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $phone; ?>"  data-placement="bottom">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span> 
</a>
```

And the JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

The tooltip appears unstyled on the left side of my screen (while it should be below the item) unstyled. My bootstrap plugin is up to date and runs css version (v3.3.6), so I am wondering if there is an external sheet I need to get for the bootstrap tooltip.

It doesnt say: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: How you included the bootstrap style sheet - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kyBwU/

Comment: @Pugazh its the top line in my head `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">` yes i pick it already up from cloudflare.

Comment: Have you even tested `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min‌​.css`? It does not exists, the URL is wrong. So easy to replicate the problem 100%. If you use a valid CDN like `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css`, then it works as expected.

Comment: How can this be, cause the rest of my bootstrap elements just work fine. And the plugin wont allow me to change the cdn, so then I am forced to work from local, and this shows me the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to call it and find a different solution. I couldnt understand why it wouldn't appear, (so indeed, it may have not been in that bootstrap version) so instead, i wrote my own tooltip with a bit of simple css. It's not the solution I wanted, but it solved my problem in the end.

Intrested?

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
    width: 120px;
    top: 100%;
     left: 50%; 
     margin-left: -60px; 
    font-size: 12px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And the modified code

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $phone;  ?>" class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $phone; ?></span>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 15):

You must put bootstrap.min.js after jquery-ui.js!
Its all.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't even use jquery ui in this case for tooltip, but it crashes for this reason. Thanks a lot. Annoying error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js is is included in your project.

Would you please try the following

Please insert this code of javascript

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
</script>
```

And in Html file add this html part

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Comment: This is kind of a nonsense answer, cause honestly, i have the same you written up there, and already told you that my css and javascript of bootstrap already worked fine. As for your question @Leothelion, `$` means  nothing more than `Jquery` term in javascript, (just shorter spelled) while  `$(document).ready()` means it will be executed once everything is done loaded

Comment: @Dorvalla well it means you did not get my comment. I made it for answerer that both are same, it depends on you which you use so i said that what is the difference.. So it was not for YOU.

Comment: @Leothelion my apologies, i misinterpreted your question.

Comment: @Dorvalla its ok mate.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `data-original-title` instead of `title`

Answer (score -1):

Also Include the "bootstrap-tooltip.js" in your HTML/Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```